# Which methods are available via DDP in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, ddp

When communicating with a Meteor server over DDP, I've found that the following methods are available:

- If you have defined a method `myMethod` in `Meteor.methods({ ... })`

  - `{"msg":"method","method":"myMethod","params":[],"id":"1"}`
- If you have enabled the `accounts-password` package

  - `{"msg":"method","method":"createUser","params":[{ ... }],"id":"1"}`
  - `{"msg":"method","method":"login","params":[{ ... }],"id":"1"}`
- If there exists a collection called `mycoll` on the server

  - `{"msg":"method","method":"/mycoll/insert","params":[{"_id":"some-doc"}],"id":"1"}`
  - `{"msg":"method","method":"/mycoll/update","params":[{ ... }],"id":"1"}`
  - `{"msg":"method","method":"/mycoll/remove","params":[{"_id":"some-doc"}],"id":"1"}`

What is now available, for example, is `{"msg":"method","method":"/mycoll/find","params":[{"_id":"some-doc"}],"id":"1"}`, however.

So is there any documentation as to what methods are available? I couldn't find any, and have only found those by trying lots of possibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undocumented, but if you want to see a full list of all available methods you can add the following code to one of your server files within your Meteor app and it'll display a sorted list of all defined `Meteor.methods` handlers at the command line, including those for collections and packages:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    console.log(Object.keys(Meteor.server.method_handlers).sort());
});
```

Granted, this doesn't provide any documentation, but it'll let you see what's available.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what was needed. I had tried printing `Meteor.methods` to the console on the client, which obviously didn't work.

Comment: On the client (e.g. in your browser's console), you just have to replace `Meteor.server` with `Meteor.connection`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the following links for DDP for meteor.

```
> https://www.meteor.com/ddp https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp
> http://meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients
> https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client
> https://github.com/mondora/asteroid
```

Comment: Thanks! I've read those before. None do answer the question, do they?